# Android: changing variable using if statement

Tags: android

This is a **OnClickListener** for button

**name** is **EditText**

I want it print only **"hi"** if nothing is entered, but **"hi" + name + "!"** if user inputs his/her name.

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (button==view) {
        String message;

        if (name.getText().toString().matches("")) {
            message = "hi!";
            return;
        }
       else {
            message = "hi" + name.getText().toString() + "!";
            return;
        }

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        display.setText(message);
    }
}
```

For some reason I got error "unreachable statement" for the line:

Toast toast =...,

And if I compile and run it, the screen will output on 2 lines instead of one, such as:

> Hi
>
> !

What did I do wrong in here?

Comment: Just remove the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have the return statement? You need to show the Toast and then return. Remove the return statements.

Comment: Edit: thanks for the help! :)  I was googling and searching this site before posting, somehow I thought the **return** is needed.

Comment: Why are you using matches? Why not simply, name.getText().toString().equals("") or better TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString())?

Comment: erm... what do you mean "simple"?  I used matches because I found it while googling and searching for solution.

Comment: I have been trying those also, especially the **isEmpy()**.  however I am running android emulator on my AMD CPU...  Whenever I refresh and re-rerun my code, it's not updated immediately (5 to 15 mins long).  It gives me "false error" and I thought my code doesn't work.  That's why I didn't use it because I thought it didn't work.  Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: matches() is a more powerful method used to match regular expression. isEmpty is a simpler method that matches only empty or null strings. If you don't need the power of regular expressions, it maybe possible to use a simpler method like isEmpty.